# Provider not set or invalid when using Web3 1.0

Tags: web3js, infura

I'm trying to use Web3 1.0 to call the balanceOf function on my contract. The error I get during runtime is as follows: `Error: Provider not set or invalid`.

The code causing the problem is as follows:

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/XKEYX'));
```

Has anyone seen this and knows what I can do to overcome it?

Thanks